# Question about a non-separable matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For this question, I am looking for answers that can provide some ideas. So be patient while you read the following.

We say that a matrix is *separable* if:

1. It can be written as an outer product of two vectors i-e $\mathbf{A=ab^T}$.
2. It has $\text{rank}\,\mathbf{(A)}=1$
3. In terms of the **singular value decomposition**, $\mathbf{A=U\Sigma V}$, only $\sigma_1\neq 0$

Lets us suppose that we have a matrix $\mathbf{B}$ with $\text{rank}\,(\mathbf{B})>1$. This matrix $\mathbf{B}$ can either be a square or a rectangular matrix but matrix dimensions are not really important here.

This matrix is clearly not separable.

My question is:what can be a good way to *measure separability of a matrix* if it is not separable in strict sense. In other words I am looking for a **metric** $0\leq m\leq 1$ that quantifies *degree of separability*.

If $m=0$, this would mean that all singular values $\sigma$'s have same energy and therefore matrix has **zero separability**. On the other hand $m=1$ implies **perfect separability**.

With this background, what will be a good way to define metric $m$ mathematically?

Answer (score 1):

The rank is the trace of the range projection. You can get the rank projection by doing 
$$
P=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+}B(B^*B+\varepsilon I)^{-1}B^*.
$$
The rank, ranging from $0$ to $n$, is the trace of $P$. And to make it run from $1$ to $0$, we can go with 
$$
\dfrac{\displaystyle\frac1{\text{Tr}(P)}-\frac1n}{\displaystyle1-\frac1n}
=\frac{\displaystyle\frac{n}{\text{Tr}(P)}-1}{n-1}
=\frac{n-\text{Tr}(P)}{(n-1)\text{Tr}(P)}.
$$
Putting everything together, 
\begin{align}
m&=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+}\frac1{n-1}\,
\left(\frac{n}{\text{Tr}(B(B^*B+\varepsilon I)^{-1}B^*)}-1\right)
\end{align}

Comment: @ Martin...thanks for your reply. I am trying to understand your answer but I think it will take some time. Can you make a reference to any book/paper that might be helpful?

Comment: Not really, sorry. I don't know about this stuff through the usual channels of linear algebra, so I'm not aware of where it is considered.

Comment: Its ok. Can you make a reference to where you found it even if it is a non LA thing?

Comment: Functional Analysis,